# Error code when trying to connect to a scanner using wpf

Tags: c#, wia

I am using WIA to connect to a scanner. I enumerate the device Infos and then try connecting to the device. I keep getting the exception.

Exception from HRESULT: 0x80210006

I am calling the code in the code behind of a WPF window.

```
        DeviceManager manager = new DeviceManagerClass();
        DeviceInfo device = null;
        foreach (DeviceInfo deviceInfo  in manager.DeviceInfos)
        {
            var ID = deviceInfo.DeviceID;
            var props = deviceInfo.Properties ;
            foreach (Property property in props)
            {
                var name = property.Name;
                var descr = property.get_Value() as string;
            }
            var type = deviceInfo.Type;
            if (type == WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType)
                device = deviceInfo;
        }
        if (device != null)
              device.Connect();
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When and where do you get this error../ also do you need to fully qualify `DeviceManager to WIA.DiviceManager`?

Comment: When it hits the device.Connect(); statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HRESULT: 0x80210006` is `WIA_ERROR_BUSY`.

From the [WIA API Error Codes page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
WIA_ERROR_BUSY        The WIA device is busy.
```

According to [Communicating with a WIA Device in Multiple Threads or Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it looks like something else may be accessing the device:

> If a thread currently has a device locked (it is actively communicating with that device) and another thread attempts to call a method that actively communicates with the device, the method returns a `WIA_ERROR_BUSY` error.

Comment: Oh, I went through this page and thought "this tells me nothing". I never checked the comments. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Yeah, this is a single thread application this is just something I was testing out so that I wouldn't have to use the TWAIN UI. It's working now after I restarted my scanner.